# How to install packages from MPR in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, mpr

Makedeb Package Repository, or [MPR](https://mpr.makedeb.org/) is something similar to [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.com) (for Arch Linux and derivatives), but for Debian based operating systems like Ubuntu.

How to install software from MPR?

For example, how can I install [Planner](https://mpr.makedeb.org/packages/planner) from MPR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to install a package using MPR.

1. Use a MPR manager like [Una](https://github.com/AFK-OS/una) (this is similar to AUR managers like `yay` or `pamac`).
2. Downloading the PKGBUILD and build it with `makedeb`.

## Installing using `una`.

1. First, install Una
2. Install the software with `una`.

#### Installing `una`.

To install `una` run:

```
git clone https://github.com/AFK-OS/una.git
cd una
./una
```

#### Installing packages via `una`.

Now, you can install packages from MPR repositories using `una`:

```
una install <name-of-software>
```

To install planner, run the command

```
una install planner
```

In Ubuntu 20.04, planner's dependency libhandy-1 is not available. You can add [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/libhandy-1) PPA, and Una will automatically download the dependency.

---

## Second method

1. Install `makedeb`.
2. Check if all the prerequisites are available in the official repositories.
3. Get the PKGBUILD.
4. Build the PKGBUILD using `makedeb`.

#### Installing `makedeb`.

To install `makedeb` on Ubuntu 20.04 and above, follow these steps:

1. Add the signing key:

   ```
   wget -qO - 'https://proget.hunterwittenborn.com/debian-feeds/makedeb.pub' | \
   gpg --dearmor | \
   sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/makedeb-archive-keyring.gpg &> /dev/null
   ```
2. Add the repository:

   ```
   echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/makedeb-archive-keyring.gpg arch=all] https://proget.hunterwittenborn.com/ makedeb main' | \
   sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/makedeb.list
   ```
3. Update the index:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

There are 3 versions of `makedeb` available, `beta`, `stable` and `alpha`, we will install the stable one.

`stable` is the tested, known-to-work release of makedeb, which is ready to be used inside of production environments.

`beta` is regularly synced from the alpha branch. This release serves as the entry point for bringing new features to the stable release and is where most testing takes place.

Lastly, `alpha` is the cutting-edge build, which receives updates as soon as changes are pushed to the Git repository, allowing users to see changes as soon as they are made. Users of this channel should prepare (and expect) for breakage from time to time.

4. Install `makedeb`:

   ```
   sudo apt install makedeb
   ```

#### Get the source code.

Go to the [official website](https://mpr.makedeb.org/) and search for the package. Get the GitHub URL for the package and copy it.

> [image: .]

> [image: .]

> [image: .]

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone <url>
```

For planner you have to run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://mpr.makedeb.org/planner.git
```

#### Check if the prerequisites are available in the official repositories.

Although you can use `makedeb` with `-s` arguemnet,  to install the dependencies, you'll have to check whether the packages are [available in the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Usually, this is not needed, but some packages depend on 3rd party packages which may not be in the default repositories, for instance, Planner depends on `libhandy` however, `libhandy` isn't available in the default repositories in Ubuntu 20.04, so you need to add a Personal Package Archive (PPA) to let `makedeb` install that package:

```
sudo sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/libhandy-1
sudo apt update
```

In later versions of Ubuntu this is not required.

#### Install using `makedeb`.

To install using `makedeb`, first, `cd` into the directory and run:

```
makedeb -s
```

For planner:

```
cd planner
makedeb -s
```

#### In a summary

In a summary you have to:

1. [Install `makedeb`](https://docs.makedeb.org/home/installing/release-types/)
2. [Get the source code of the package](https://mpr.makedeb.org/packages/planner)
3. Cd into the cloned directory and run `makedeb -s`.

#### All the commands in a summary.

These commands for installing planner, read the comments before proceeding with any command:

```
### Add the required PPA.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/libhandy-1
sudo apt update
 

### Install makdeb

wget -qO - 'https://proget.hunterwittenborn.com/debian-feeds/makedeb.pub' | \
gpg --dearmor | \
sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/makedeb-archive-keyring.gpg &> /dev/null

echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/makedeb-archive-keyring.gpg arch=all] https://proget.hunterwittenborn.com/ makedeb main' | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/makedeb.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt install makedeb

### Get the source code.

sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://mpr.makedeb.org/planner.git

### Install

cd planner
makedeb -si
```

**NOTE**: Installation of `makedeb` is needed only for the first time, in future, you can skip the installation of `makedeb` and simply get the prerequisites and proceed for building.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. +1. I found that `makedeb -si` automatically downloads the dependencies and installs the package, just like `makepkg -si` in Arch.

Comment: I have updated the answer with Una. After setting up una once and for all, it is as simple as `una install planner`.

Comment: hi @ArchismanPanigrahi :) yup, makedeb isn't supposed to be used directly by new users, since helpers are much easier to use (which is I developed una)